# Mount directory as virtual dvd/cd (not disk)

Tags: macos, mount, dvd

I would like to emulate mounting as a virtual cd or dvd, so Mac OS X Lion thinks it is a real cd / dvd.

I have already tried [ToastMount](http://toastmount.sourceforge.net/), however it hasn't been compiled for Intel processors and I can't open the Xcode project file in Xcode 4, because it is incompatible.

I probably could dualboot my Mac and install Snow Leopard and Xcode 3 to compile it for Intel, however this seems like a long process just to get this software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daemon Tools Lite for Mac, seems to do this.

http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtMacLite